# How to change HeidiSQL completion shortcut?

Tags: heidisql

My native language is not English, and on my system, the `ctrl-space` key binding is used for switching input method. While in `HeidiSQL`, this key binding is used for SQL code completion. Is it possible to rebind this function to another key, say, `alt-/`?

(`database.table` completion works fine here. `SQL` command like `SELECT * FROM db WHERE col = 'sth'` won't.)

Answer (score 2):

Shortcuts are customizable in Tools > Preferences > Shortcuts. But that special `Ctrl+Space` shortcut is *not* customizable. It's hardcoded in the sources.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think there are tremendous amount of non-native English speakers that rely heavily on the input method, and `ctrl-space` is very common for this purpose. Even there's an alternative shortcut to replace `ctrl-space` key bindings in `eclipse` and `intellij` . **hardcoded** in the source is not a good idea.

Comment: I didn't say that this is a good idea, I just replied to your question.In what way is Ctrl+Space specific to English language?

Comment: Oh, I mean thank you for your answer, and just added some comment on the current status of HeidiSQL design. Please don't mind. It's my bad that I didn't express clearly.

Comment: I change input languages all the time, and by default in both Windows and Linux it is `Win+Space` as it should be.